# how to Drill Down chart ,create Multiple charts by click

Tags: javascript

I have a chart, when I click on each bar,it will create 3 different charts accordingly,i have a click event which does it for me,so i need 3 different charts in 3 different div,its working but since the demands are increasing its becoming a nightmare,the sub charts also should be clickable ,is there a reasonable,manageable way to do so?like layered or something ? actually I m not professional is js,and could not find anything related,i have created a very simple sample to make my pint better:

HTML:

```
<div style="width:100%">
<div id="chart" style="width:30% ;float:left"></div>
<div id="chart2" style="width:35%;float:right"></div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
        $("#chart").kendoChart({
          series: [{
            data: [1, 2],
            color: function(point) {
              if (point.value > 1) {
                return "red";
              }

              // use the default series theme color
            }
          }],  
          seriesClick:seriesClick  
        });
          function seriesClick(){
          $("#chart2").kendoChart({
          series: [{
            data: [1, 2],
            color: function(point) {
              if (point.value > 1) {
                return "blue";
              }
            }
          }],  
        });

          }
```

here is the live sample:[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sqd6v0db/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are trying to create a charting component in JS, you should use a standard charting library for your purpose. Here is a free, but amazing one.

https://www.chartjs.org/

Comment: i could not find a chart im looking for ,in any js library

Comment: whats your suggestion for my problem?whats the best way to show what i have asked in the question?